# ruby on rails - indexing ancestry records with Sunspot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, solr

I'm trying to index the ancestor categories of products for the purposes of faceting using Sunspot (and searching, but if I can solve one I'll solve the other). The code works okay for the immediate parent, but I can't work out how to index the grandparents....

In this scenario, I've used Ancestry gem to create a category tree structure, and each product is mapped to one or more leaf nodes in the tree.

I'm new to rails so the syntax is a little foreign to me, but if you see the text:categories loop, I'm trying to basically iterate each of the ancestors of the product and index the category name of each products ancestors.

If you could help me fix the syntax, or code that would be great.

```
searchable do
    text :aux_description, :long_description, :name, :on_special, :part_number, :short_description
    text :categories do 

    categories.map { |category| category.name 
        Rails.logger.debug { "indexing category " + category.name }
        category.ancestors.each { |ancestor| ancestor.name
         Rails.logger.debug { "indexing category " + ancestor.name }}
      }
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The block that you pass to `text` needs to return an array of strings. So if you just needed to index category names this would work:

```
text :categories do
  categories.map { |category| category.name }
end
```

If you need to index the ancestors of each category too then you could use a temporary variable and return that. (The last statement in a block is the 'return' value).

```
text :categories do
  names = []
  categories.each { |category| names << category.name }
  categories.each { |category| category.ancestors.each { |ancestor| names << ancestor.name } if category.ancestors }
  names
end
```

Or you could eliminate the local variable:

```
text :categories do
  categories.map { |category| [category.name] + (category.ancestors ? category.ancestors.map { |ancestor| ancestor.name } : []) }.flatten
end
```

Be wary of adding logging statements at the end of a block because it will alter the value returned from that block.

Comment: Ok thanks Steve. I ended up solving it another way less efficient way. Ruby is definitely a different language than what I"m used to, certainly interesting.